# 2-way binding inside directive loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am trying to write a simple form builder for my clients. The idea being for them to create a simple form that they can use later on different occasions.

For that I am at this point creating a directive to parse the json form back to html trough a directive.

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('formbuilder', ['$timeout', '$compile', '$parse', function($timeout, $compile, $parse) {
        return {
        restrict:'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
                form: '=ngModel'
            },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    var bones = scope.form.structure;

                    scope.formId = scope.form.title.replace(/\W+/g, " ").replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase();

                    var html = '<form id="{{formId}}" class="row">';

                    angular.forEach(bones, function(bone, key) {
                        if(bone.type == 'text' || bone.type == 'checkbox') {
                            scope[key] = $parse('form.data.'+key)(scope);
                            html += '<input-field class="col s12"><input type="'+bone.type+'" id="'+bone.type+key+'" ng-model="form.data['+key+']" /> <label for="'+bone.type+key+'">'+bone.label+'</label></input-field> ';
                        }
                    })

                    html += '<p>{{form.data.input1}}</p>';

                    html += '</form>';
                    element.append($compile(html)(scope));
           })
        }
     };
}]);
```

Problem is: I am looping through the items to find parse them back into html. That is clearly not working as expected. I can $parse it but then the 2-way binding is lost...

Any thoughts ?

The json structure is:

```
$scope.form = {
        title: 'My first form',
        structure: {
            input1: {
                type: 'text',
                label: 'Input label'
            },
            input2: {
                type: 'checkbox',
                label: 'This is a checkbox'
            },
            input3: {
                type: 'checkbox',
                label: 'This is a CHECKED checkbox'
            }
        },
        data: {
            input1: 'Yannick',
            input2: false,
            input3: true
        }
    }
```

Comment: *That is clearly not working as expected.* What do you expect?

Comment: Using the ngModelController with isolate scope and two-way binding is problemmatic. Can you explain what you are trying to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using the `ng-model` attribute which instantiates the ngModelController. Instead use one-time binding:

```
 <formbuilder form="::form"></formbuilder>
```

In the directive, use isolate scope with one-way (`<`) binding:

```
.directive('formbuilder', ['$timeout', '$compile', '$parse', function($timeout, $compile, $parse) {
    return {
    restrict:'AE',
    /*
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
            form: '=ngModel'
        },
    */
    scope: { form: "<" },
```

This will bind the `form` object *reference* to the isolate scope. Changes to the *contents* by the directive inputs will be shared with the parent scope object. There is no need to do two-way binding of the object *reference*.

Also for obvious reasons, don't use bracket notation for the property accessor, instead use dot notation:

```
  //html += '<input ng-model="form.data['+key+']"' 

  //USE dot notation
    html += '<input ng-model="form.data.'+key+'"'
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR.](https://plnkr.co/edit/VzxSDKCZgBAT0dLctKMk?p=preview)